# NodeJS API to upload image to S3 not returning response

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, koa

I am trying to upload image to AWS S3 bucket using NodeJS. The issue I am facing it is while the image is getting saved but the API is returning 404(Not Found). Here is my controller code:

```
async UploadProfileImage(ctx) {
    try {       

        var file = ctx.request.files.profileImage;

        if (file) {
            fs.readFile(file.path, (err, fileData) => {
                var resp = s3Utility.UploadProfileImageToS3(file.name, fileData);
                //Not reaching here. Although E3 tag printing in console.
                console.log(resp);
                ctx.status = 200;
                ctx.body = { response: 'file Uploaded!' };
            });
        }
        else {
            ctx.status = 400;
            ctx.body = { response: 'File not found!' };
        }

    } catch (error) {
        ctx.status = 500;
        ctx.body = { response: 'There was an error. Please try again later!' };
    }

}
```

Utility Class I am using is:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const crypto = require("crypto");
var fs = require('fs');
const mime = require('mime-types');

export class S3Utility {
    constructor() { }
    async UploadProfileImageToS3(fileName, data) {
        let randomId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
        AWS.config.update({ region: "Region", accessKeyId: "KeyID", secretAccessKey: "SecretAccessKey" });
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var imageName = randomId + fileName;
        var params = {
            Bucket: "BucketName"
            Key: imageName,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: mime.lookup(fileName)
        };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error: ', err);
                    reject(new Error(err.message));
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve({
                        response: data,
                        uploadedFileName: imageName
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }   
}

const s3Utility: S3Utility = new S3Utility();

export default s3Utility;
```

The code is uploading file on S3 but it is not returning proper response. Upon testing this endpoint on postman, I get "Not Found" message. However, I can see E Tag getting logged in console. I don't know what is going wrong here. I am sure it has something to do with promise. Can someone please point out or fix the mistake?

**Edit:**
Using async fs.readFile does the trick.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const fileData = await fs.readFile(file.path, "binary"); 
var resp = await s3Utility.UploadProfileImageToS3(file.name, fileData);
```

Comment: you have to await the Promise returned from UploadProfileImageToS3

Comment: `s3Utility.UploadProfileImageToS3` is an asynchronous call, but you are not handling async anywhere

Comment: Yes. You are right. That was my assumption as well. I can do it in a different way. const fs = require('fs').promises; const fileData = await fs.readFile(file.path, "binary"); var resp = await s3Utility.UploadProfileImageToS3(file.name, fileData);

Comment: You can find a complete example here: https://github.com/golkhandani/image-hero